# How do I insert a value into DB table when every time button action is performed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication, one-time-password

Hii am working on a project in which when a button is clicked it should generate an OTP and saves the generated value in the sql database.

**My php code for OTP :**

```
<?php

$string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$string_shuffled = str_shuffle($string);

$half = substr($string_shuffled, 1, 7);

echo $half ;

?>
```

**My HTML code for button to generate OTP in login.php :**

```
<input class="button" name="generate" id="generate" tabindex="5" value="Generate Password" type="submit">
```

**My php action when the above button is clicked :**

```
if(isset($_POST['generate']))
    {
           $string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
           $string_shuffled = str_shuffle($string);

           $half = substr($string_shuffled, 1, 7);

           $query = "INSERT INTO `san_login`.`user_login` (`password`)   VALUES ('".$half."')";
           }
```

The problem is I couldn't get the output of $half to store into my table 'password' column

Comment: you don't EXECUTE your query. you're just defining a string which happens to contain some SQL. It's like writing "I'm the president of the USA" on a piece of paper, and then wondering why you don't have a secret service escort yet.

Comment: @MarcB Let me rephrase my quest , I created a button in HTML under the id='generate' which would allow me to perform this "if" function. The if function consist of algorithm to generate my OTP .
Now am not sure how to get that generated otp and save in my DB .

Answer (score 1):

You did not execute your query.

You need to run this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `san_login`.`user_login` (`password`)   VALUES ('".$half."')";
```

execute your query like this(e.g in mysqli_)

```
 mysqli_query($your_link,$query);
```

see details [mysqli_query][1]
[1]: https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: How can I place my OTP algorithm inside my button and save the result in the 'password' column in DB ??